# C++ += operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

I overloaded the += operator, my code looks like:
Matrix is just a vector>

If I do something like:

```
matrix1+=matrix2;
cout<<matrix1; // i have overloaded <<
```

The code compiles with no error but there's no output.
Can someone point out what's wrong with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic: Pass your arguments by const-reference `const&` instead of non-const ones.

Comment: How have you overloaded `<<`?

Comment: You say there is a problem with no output, and you say you overloaded the `operator<<` but you don't show us that code?

Comment: Why don't you show your definition of `Matrix<T>`?

Comment: @Holt I tried to pass by const& at first but in the transform function I am putting the data into vector a. In this case it can't be a const. Do you suggest me to create a new vector instead of putting the result into a? Thanks!

Comment: @FantasticMrFox It works well with other matrix so I guess it's not the problem of <<.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. When there is no output we need to see the `<<` overload. Can you print a matrix that is not a result of `+=` ?

Comment: @user463035818 Yes I can.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the output buffer ([`cout.flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush))

Comment: could you remind us what overload of `transform` this is? I never can remember and to me it looks fishy that 3rd and 4th parameters are from different containers `right.begin(), begin(),`

Comment: @TommyAndersen It works! Can you please explain the reason? Thanks!

Comment: even if you are 100% sure that your `<<` overload is fine, we still need to see it to reproduce your problem. and btw there is a strong correlation between being sure that the error is not in a place and the error actually being in that place :P

Comment: @user463035818 I am basically doing a add operation on two input containers and put the result back to the first one.

Comment: @user463035818 So there's output after I do cout.flush() I guess my oeprator << is fine.

Comment: "guess is fine" wont help. We need to see the code or an example that does not use `<<`

Comment: Completely unrelated to the the answer: Question title, usage of operator += usage of std::transform, code snippet, missing relevant code. That's why this got closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is a buffered output stream. That means that the content you write to the stream is written to a buffer. This buffer is flushed whenever, a newline character is encountered, or you manually instruct your stream to flush the buffer using: [`std::basic_ostream::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush).

In your example you could add: `<< '\n'` at the end or you could call: `cout.flush();` both would flush your output. Had the stream not been buffered, like [`std::cerr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr) the output would have been printed without the need of newline or flush.

Note: The reason why the newline character flushes the output, is that `std::cout` in your case points to a line buffered terminal. If it had not, you would have to manually call `flush`.

Comment: or `<< std::endl` for newline and flush together

Comment: Use of `std::endl` is discouraged. See: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/357 and https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rio-endl

Comment: Both of those say not to use `std::endl` *unless* you actually want to do `\n` and flush at the same time. Use of `std::endl` is discouraged when used in place of `\n`, but not when you actually want to do the one thing `std::endl` was designed to do, right?

Comment: Not really... "The `endl` manipulator is mostly equivalent to `'\n'` and `"\n"`; as most commonly used it simply slows down output by doing redundant `flush()`s. This slowdown can be significant compared to `printf`-style output.". If you really want to use `\n` and flush (two flushes in a line-buffer) use `<< '\n' << std::flush` instead. Atleast it shows that you do it on purpose... a comment explaining why might a good addition as well. :)

Comment: Also note the note: "For `cin`/`cout` (and equivalent) interaction, there is no reason to flush; that's done automatically. For writing to a file, there is rarely a need to flush."

Comment: Surely there are some instances where you might want to flush `cin`/`cout`. What if you are debugging and want something to print *right now*

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic then you simply add a newline (which will flush when the output is written to the terminal). Or if you don't want a newline, you simply use `flush`, in that case `endl` would not be relevant anyway as it would result in a line break.